# CoreAnimation CATransform3DScale hides a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am trying to make a view have the effect of popping out of the screen. However, each time I try to use CATransform3DScale, the view disappears. I have tried adjusting with the zPosition, but that has not worked. I am using 'TheAnimation' from cocoapods. I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

```
private func setupAnimation(){
        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform.m34 = -1.0/500.0
        //containerViews[0].layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        containerViews[0].layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0, 0, 1)
        let animation = BasicAnimation(keyPath: .transform)
        animation.fromValue = CATransform3DIdentity
        animation.toValue = transform
        animation.duration = 3.0
        animation.setAnimationDidStop { _ in
            print("hello")
            self.containerViews[0].layer.zPosition = 0
        }
        animation.animate(in: containerViews[0].layer)
    }
```

View disappears and then reappears after the animation duration.

Comment: Try to give us a better description of *"popping out of the screen"* ... Are you trying to start with a very small view and have it "grow"?

Comment: transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0, 0, 1)   should be increased from 1. It was a mistake on my part and not understanding what the transform was supposed to do

Comment: Could you give an answer to your own question and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 0, 0, 1) should be increased from 1. It was a mistake on my part and not understanding what the transform was supposed to do

Also from value should not be identity